# Unable to use ajax with php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to show a table on a webpage. Table get content from mysql table. I have a delete button in my table in each row. I want that whenever i click on delete button that row should get deleted from database and webpage both.

here is my code

```
<script>
function ajaxFunction(str){
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-example.php?name="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php
// Connect to the database
 $dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM `file`';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);

// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
// Make sure there are some files in there
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
}
else {

    // Print the top of a table
   echo " <table width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
            </tr>";

    // Print each file

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                <td><a href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class= 'button' value='delete' name='delete' onClick='ajaxFunction({$row['name']})'></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='button' value='edit' name='edit'></td>
            </tr>";
    }

    // Close table
   echo " </table>";

 }

 // Free the result
 $result->free();
 }
 else
 {
 echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
 echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
 }
 echo "<div id='txtHint'>Yours</div>";
 $dbLink->close();
 ?>
```

here is my ajax-example.php

```
  <?php
  // Connect to the database
  $name=$_GET['name'];
  $dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'test');
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
   }

  // Query for a list of all existing files

  $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM `file` where `name`="$name"';
  $result = $dbLink->query($sql);

  // Check if it was successfull
  if($result) {
  // Make sure there are some files in there
  if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
  }
  else {
    // Print the top of a table
    echo '<table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
            </tr>';

    // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                <td><a href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><input type='button' style='display:none' class= 'button' value='delete' name='delete'><input type='button' style='display:none' class='button' value='edit' name='edit'></td>
                     </tr>";    
}
    // Close table
    echo "</table>";
    }
    // Free the result
    $result->free();
    }
     else
    {
       echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
      echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
     }

     // Close the mysql connection
     $dbLink->close();
     ?>
```

This file is actually try to print the row in which i click on the delete button. I am trying to do this first. If the row is getting selected then deleting it won't be a problem.
But webpage only show table and pressing delete button won't change content "yours".
I don't know what to do. Where i am making mistake?

/Note/
This functionality is a part of a feature. Actually those delete button and edit button should be visible when i click on checkbox. For that i use javascript. But here i am not showing it. All i am able to find is that ajaxFunction() is not getting called. Because i try using alert("hi") in it and nothing happen on webpage on clicking on delete button.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Using ___MYSQLi___ isnt mean you are safe from sql injection .. yet you need to ___Escape/sanitise EVERY SINGLE REQUEST___ and if you are using jquery than try ajax with that.. its lot more easier and effective

Comment: Are you sure mysql accepts double quotes around string litterals? On the other hand, don't use a GET request if the main purpose of it is to POST an information to the server.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
    ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $(this).nextAll("input").show() : $(this).nextAll("input").hide();
});
$("input[name='delete']").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
$("input[name='edit']").on("click", function () {
    
    });
});
</script>
This is my jquery code. Dont know how to use ajax with it.

Comment: @Sebas i replace get from post and also "$name" from $name but still no result

Answer (score 1):

Use the $ajax method using Jquery javascript library.

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Here you can define data type: `type: "POST",`, the url of which you want the results and you can pass in data also for your sql query while clause.`data: { id: delete_id}`

You can study it here. its very easy. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

1. you store the id in a `<input type="hidden">` then have value using `$('selector'),val()` and assign it to the variable `delete_id=$('selector'),val();` selector will be class or id like this: `$('#id')` or `$('.class')`. Now pass the data in ajax.

Comment: yes i tried that but i got stuck. Here you are explicitly giving John to name but in my case how can i get the id or name column of the row which i want to delete.

Comment: In the lower part i have written that also. data: { id: delete_id} like this.

Comment: you want me to replace `<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><input type='button' style='display:none' class= 'button' value='delete' name='delete'><input type='button' style='display:none' class='button' value='edit' name='edit'></td>` with `<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><input type='button' style='display:none' data: {id: $row['id']} class= 'button' value='delete' name='delete'><input type='button' style='display:none' class='button' value='edit' name='edit'></td>` ?

Comment: just take a input hidden field in each row of your data to store the id that you can pass on through ajax and use it in where clause

Comment: ok i understand what you are trying to say `<td><input type='hidden' id ='repo'>$row['id']</td>`

Comment: and in the `$("input[name='delete']").on("click", function () { $(this).closest("tr").remove(); });` do this

Comment: `$("input[name='delete']").on("click", function () { $(this).closest("tr").remove(); delete_id=$('#repo') });`

Comment: no write it like this. <td><input type='hidden' id ='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>$row['id']</td> then have the value on .click event like this $(this).val();...it will give you the value of the row that you have clicked.

Comment: The idea is when you click the delete button or input..either you can have the value of $row['id']; print like the following <td><input type='hidden' id ='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>$row['id']</td>  and then on clik event take the value like $(this).val() and save it to the variable and pass it through ajax

Comment: Have you got my pint?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40696/discussion-between-shams-and-sumit-rathore)

Comment: $("input[name='delete']").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    var delete_id=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "change.php",
  data: { id: delete_id }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

    });
 i am doing this is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

i think i need to move the javascript at head of html.. i ever happen that too... after i move, and that work fine.. hope that can help you..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   <-- your function -->
</script>
</head>
   .
   .

   ,
```